# Spring boot: Logout doesn't invalidate the session

Tags: java, session, spring-boot

I use the following web security configuration for my simple spring Restful API. But making a POST/GET request to `/logout` doesn't help and the user would be still authenticated (as it can still access `/greeting` endpoint which I accepts `GET` requests).

I tried different approaches in the answers previously posted on SO (e.g. adding `invalidateHTTPSession(true)`, making POST request instead of GET request) but still it doesn't work.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().
    httpBasic().and().
    logout().logoutUrl("/logout").invalidateHttpSession(true).logoutSuccessUrl("/greeting").permitAll().and().
    csrf().disable();
  }

}
```

Comment: You are using basic authentication, you cannot logout with basic authentication. Each time a request is made the username/password is send to the server as part of the request, so even after a logout the user simply logs in again.

Comment: You mean basic authentication doesn't create a session and keeps the user authentication state in it ? I'm not planning to use third party authentiators (facebook, twitter, etc.) for my app. Basically, I just want to let the user sign in, and use the service while he/she is signed in and logout. Is there any other way of authentication to have this functionality ?

Comment: No I'm not saying that... I'm only saying that the nature of basic authentication is to send the username/password as a request header with every request. Which leads to a login directly after logout and hence you cannot logout with basic authentication (unless you are using JavaScript and ajax you might be able to clear the client side header, but if you are using a plain browser that isn't possible).

Comment: I'm new to the web security. What is the best practice here? from the server pov, is it to issue a bearer at login, and use the bearer instead of username/password for the rest of calls?